# How to upgrade NPM from 1.x to 2.x?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running windows 7 and when I installed node.js, it came with NPM 1.4.3.  I need NPM 2.0.2 so I ran the following;

```
C:\proj>npm install -g npm@2.0.2
npm http GET http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/npm/2.0.2
npm http 200 http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/npm/2.0.2
npm http GET http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/npm/-/npm-2.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/npm/-/npm-2.0.2.tgz
C:\Users\pgreen\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\pgreen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@2.0.2 C:\Users\pgreen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```

The output does show that I'm using a local nexus plugin to do NPM Repository proxy, but I have no reason to suspect that is causing any problems.

After the install I see:

```
C:\proj>npm --version
1.4.3
```

So what am I missing to make npm version 2.0.2 available on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to [RTFM](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows):

> Upgrading on Windows
>
> By default, npm is installed alongside node in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs. npm's globally installed packages (including,
>   potentially, npm itself) are stored separately in a user-specific
>   directory (which is currently
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm). Because the installer puts
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs before
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm on your PATH, it will always
>   use version of npm installed with node instead of the version of npm
>   you installed using npm -g install npm@. To get around this,
>   you can do one of the following:
>
> ```
> Option 1: edit your Windows installation's PATH to put C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm before C:\Program Files
> ```
>
> (x86)\nodejs. Remember that you'll need to restart cmd.exe (and
>   potentially restart Windows) when you make changes to PATH or how npm
>   is installed.
>
> ```
> Option 2: remove both of
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd
>
> Option 3: navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs with cmd.exe and then run the installation without -g:
> ```
>
> npm install npm
>
> If you installed npm with the node.js installer, after doing one of
>   the previous steps go into C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
>   and copy the file named npmrc in the new npm folder, which should be
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm. This will
>   tell the new npm where the global installed packages are. See the
>   point below for more details.
>
> (See also the point below if you're running Windows 7 and don't have
>   the directory C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm.)